# Sending mails twice to SOME recipients with swiftmailer

Tags: php, database, email, cron, swiftmailer

I'm developing an application that gets mail addresses from a database and then send an email to those addresses. In my script first I get the recipients, then save the messages into disk and after a while using CRON I send them. The number of messages in the spool directory matches the number of recipients. The problem is that some recipients receive the email twice. And the weirdest thing is not everyone receive the email twice, just 40 recipients of 700. I checked the database to see if some addresses were duplicated but that's not the case, and the script that sends the spooled messages doesn't have a loop, so I'm pretty lost here. Any help you could give would be amazing.
Thanks in advance.
Here's the code where I create the messages:

```
$spool = new Swift_FileSpool(__DIR__."/spool");

// Setup the transport and mailer
$transport = Swift_SpoolTransport::newInstance($spool);


$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$result = array();
foreach($cliente as $cliente){
    $archivo = explode("/", $cliente->pdf);
    $correo = explode(";", $cliente->mail);
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance($asunto);
    if(is_dir($directorio . "/" . $mes)){
        $prueba[$x] = rename($cliente->pdf, $directorio . "/" . $mes . "/".$archivo[1]);
    }
    else{
        mkdir($directorio . "/" . $mes, 0777);
        chmod($directorio . "/" . $mes, 0777);
        $prueba[$x] = rename($cliente->pdf, $directorio . "/" . $mes . "/" .$archivo[1]);
    }

    $fp=fopen("datos/clientes.txt","a") or die("No se pudo crear el archivo");
    fwrite($fp, "$cliente->nombre,,$cliente->mail,,$cliente->pdf" . PHP_EOL);
    fclose($fp);

    if($prueba[$x]){
        $copiados++;
    }
    else{
        $errorcopiar[] = "No se ha podido cambiar de carpeta la factura correspondiente al cliente " . $cliente->nombre;
    }
    $cuerpo = "this is the message body";
    //Se crea el mensaje sin archivo adjunto.
    if (!$archivosubido){     
        $message->setFrom($origen);
        $message->setReturnPath($returnpath);
        $message->setTo($correo);
        $message->setReplyTo($returnpath);
        $message->setBody($cuerpo, 
                'text/html');
        $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($directorio . "/" . $mes . "/" .$archivo[1]));
    }
    //Se crea el mensaje con archivo adjunto.
    else{
        $message->setFrom($origen);
        $message->setReturnPath($returnpath);
        $message->setTo($correo);
        $message->setBody($cuerpo, 
                'text/html');
        $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($directorio . "/" . $mes . "/" .$archivo[1]));
        $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('subidos/' . $archivosubido));
   }
   //Se envía el mensaje.
    $result[$x] = $mailer->send($message);        
    $x++;
}
```

And here's the code where I send the spooled messages:

```
$spool = new Swift_FileSpool(__DIR__."/spool");

$transport = Swift_SpoolTransport::newInstance($spool);

$realtransport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($servidor,
        25)
        ->setUsername($user)
        ->setPassword($password);

$spool = $transport->getSpool();
$spool->setMessageLimit(10000);
$spool->setTimeLimit(10000);

$sent = $spool->flushQueue($realtransport, $fallos);
```

Comment: "if you wanna take a look at the code just let me know" - yes please.

Comment: I just include it, I hope you can help me